# What happens to cations after depolarization/repolarization in cardiac muscle?

Tags: cardiology, sodium, calcium, potassium

In the depolarization/repolarization of the cardiac cell cations such as sodium, calcium, and potassium flow in and out of the cell creating an action potential. My question is what happens to these cations once the depolarization takes place? Are they used again for repolarization? Are they stored somewhere in the cell such as the sarcoplasmic reticulum awaiting use?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/why-is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-equilibrium-potential-of-an-ion-using-the-ne/57066#57066 has an answer that's probably helpful.